# Swift: prepareforsegue method is not called

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITableView along with UISearchBar. I displayed some coredata value such as name of employees in the tableview. If I select the row on a particular employee name, the details of the employee should be displayed in the another view controller, and I did this using this "override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)" segue method.

The problem is, whenever i filtered the employee name using search bar, and used the tap the filtered employee name on the tableview, the "override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)" is not called. But without search I can able to navigate to the detailed viewcontroller with the selected employee. But in case of filtering the name using searchbar I couldn't achieve the segue navigation to the employee detail. 
Please tell me the reason why it is not navigate after search results Or Suggest me with the solution.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let object : Any
    if(searchActive){
        let indexPath = self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        object = self.filteredEmployees[(indexPath?.row)!]
    }
    else{
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        object = self.employees[(indexPath?.row)!]
    }
    let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
    //controller.detailItem = object
    controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
    controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
    controller.employees = object as! EmployeeDetails

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.value1, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    cell?.textLabel!.numberOfLines = 0
    cell?.textLabel!.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    cell?.textLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)
    if(searchActive){
        var filter: EmployeeDetails? = nil
        filter =  self.filteredEmployees[indexPath.row]
        cell?.textLabel?.text = String(format:"%@  %@", (filter?.firstName!)!, (filter?.lastName!)!)
        cell?.detailTextLabel!.text = String(format:"%@", (filter?.title!)!)

    } else
    {
        var employee : EmployeeDetails? = nil
        employee =  self.employees[indexPath.row]
        cell?.textLabel?.text = String(format:"%@  %@", (employee?.firstName!)!, (employee?.lastName!)!)
        cell?.detailTextLabel!.text = String(format:"%@", (employee?.title!)!)

    }
    return cell!
}
```

Comment: can you show your code of cellforRowat and didselectRow

Comment: do you call the segue based on the **indexpath** selected?

Comment: @Anbu - please wait I will add my code here

Comment: @DhivyaSundaram - ya sure

Comment: @praveen - yes I used indexpath

Comment: @DhivyaSundaram do all the indexpath have the segue?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik pls find the image of code block

Comment: @DhivyaSundaram - I asked your your code of cellforRowat and didselectRow, problem in didselect or tap action problem not in segue

Comment: @PraveenKumar - segue connection is common between the tableview & the detail view controller.

Comment: @DhivyaSundaram - dont add the image add the code always

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik - i didnt use didselectrowatindexpath, am implementing the navigation using the segue. And also tried with the didselectrowatindexpath it is not called.

Comment: @DhivyaSundaram - dear sister I think you used any Gesture or button action in your cellforRowat can you show ur code , its better to find the excat issue

Comment: @DhivyaSundaram - we dont know what your project contains, if you add some additional information it is better to identify the issye

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik - nothing i used in cellForRow, wait let me add the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146047/discussion-between-anbu-karthik-and-dhivya-sundaram).